# Limiting the features of an embedded python instance

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-embedding

Is there a way to limit the abilities of python scripts running under an embedded interpretor? Specifically I wish to prevent the scripts from doing things like the following:

- Importing python extension modules (ie .pyd modules), except those specifically allowed by the application.
- Manipulating processes in any way (ie starting new processes, or terminating the application).
- Any kind of networking.
- Manipulating the file system (eg creating, modifying and deleting files).

Comment: Is http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/ an option?

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no easy way to prevent those things on CPython. Your options are:

1. Edit CPython source code and remove things you don't want - provide mocking methods for all those things. Very error-prone and hard to do. This is the approach of Google's App Engine.
2. Use [Restricted Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/). However, with it you can't prevent your user from exhausting the memory available or running infinite eat-all-cpu loops.
3. Use another python implementation. PyPy has a [sandbox mode](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/sandbox.html) you can use. [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) runs under java and I guess java can be sandboxed.

Comment: Well I'm not to worried about scripts crashing/freezing the application, more when a hostile plug-in say downloads and executes a file from the internet, changes system settings, etc.  

I guess I could edit the CPython implementation, for some things I guess just not compiling the module to start with will be suitable, and if I guess I could hook the module loader to check a whitelist of safe pyd modules.

Is there any info around somewhere on simply removing modules/objects from the python compile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/hacking-python-at-runtime/) can be helpful. You have an example provided on how to work with the ast.

Comment: "ACCESS DENIED", I really hate colleges internet restrictions...will check this later when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

What you want it Google's [Unladen Swallow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unladen_Swallow) project that Python version of [App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appengine) runs on.

Modules are severely restricted, `ctypes` are not allowed, sockets are matched against some policy or other, in other words you get a sandboxed version of Python, in line with their Java offering.

I'd like to point out that this makes the system almost useless. Well useless for anything cooler than yet another [App Engine] App. Forget monkey-patching system modules, and even access to own stack is restricted. Totally un-dynamic-like.

OT: games typically embed LUA for scripting, perhaps you should check it out.